# Error at the end of my conditional : TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, conditional-statements

Ok, I'm trying to access a local XML doc that consists of chapters, each with several pages of text. I have a conditional that listens for a button click and "turns the page" so to speak. The "if" works fine: It cycles through the pages until it reaches the end. But the "else" condition doesn't work. It won't even trace anything. I know it's because of this error:

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at thisArray/textLoader()

...but not sure how to fix it. Do I need to totally scrap my method for cycling through the text, or am I just missing something minor? Sorry if some of this code is sloppy... I've tweaked it quite a bit trying to get it working. Thanks for the help.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
package  {



import as3101.ui.formatA;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;



public class thisArray extends MovieClip {

        //XML Vars
        private var xml:XML;
        private var storyKeys:Dictionary = new Dictionary();    
        private var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        private var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("storyXML.xml");
        //Text and Button Vars 
        private var formatting:formatA;
        private var txta:TextField = new TextField();
        private var storyBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var count:uint = 0;
        private var storyText:XMLList;
        private var nxtBtn:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function thisArray() {

            addChild(storyBox);
            storyBox.addChild(txta);
            storyBox.x = 0;
            storyBox.y = 0;
            txta.x = 0;
            txta.y = 0;
            storyBox.width = 500
            storyBox.height = 400;
            storyBox.buttonMode = true;
            storyBox.mouseChildren = false;
            xmlLoader.load(url);
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoad);
//external class formatA sets my text for size, font, etc...
            formatting = new formatA();
            formatting.defField = txta;
            txta.defaultTextFormat = formatting.myFormat;
            txta.wordWrap = true;

        trace ("class loaded: " + this);


    }

    private function onXmlLoad(e:Event):void {

        xml = new XML(xmlLoader.data);
        trace("XML Loaded");
        storyText = xml.chapters.chapter.page;
        txta.text = storyText[count];
        buttonMaker();

        }

    public function textLoader(e:MouseEvent):void {


                count++;
                if(count < txta.length)
                {
                trace("hi");
                txta.text = storyText[count];
                } else if (count == storyText.length) {
                    trace("bye");
                    removeChild(nxtBtn);


                }
    }


    public function buttonMaker() {

                    nxtBtn.graphics.lineStyle(3,333333);
                    nxtBtn.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
                    nxtBtn.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,30);
                    nxtBtn.graphics.endFill();
                    nxtBtn.x = 480;
                    nxtBtn.y = 220;
                    addChild(nxtBtn);
                    nxtBtn.buttonMode = true;
                    nxtBtn.name = ("nextButton");
                    nxtBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, textLoader);

    }
```

Here is my XML doc:

< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >

< storyText >

< chapters >

< chapter id="0" name="one" >

```
       < page num="0" > Text Block A < /page >

       < page num="1" > Text Block B < /page >

       < page num="2" > Text Block C < /page >

      < page num="3" > Text Block D < /page >
```

< /chapter >

< chapter id="1" name="two" >
< /chapter >

< chapter id="2" name="three" >
< /chapter >

< /storyAnswers >

< /chapters >

< /storyText >

Answer (score 0):

`if(count < txta.length)
       {
            trace("hi");
            txta.text = storyText[count];
       }`

This first line should probably be `if(count < storyText.length)`. Right now it's comparing the length of the string associated in the textfield `txta` and comparing it to your incrementing integer that needs to stay within the array `storyText`'s scope.

Another thing is it's hard to tell what's going on with your loaded XML without it being posted. After you load it with `storyText = xml.chapters.chapter.page;` run a trace on storyText.length to make sure you're actually working with something that isn't returning null.

Comment: Thanks guys I will give these a try this evening and see if it solves the problem. If not, I'll upload a sample of the xml file as well.

Comment: when I switched (count < txta.length) to (count < storyText.length), my button no longer works. It just sits there on the first block of text. I'm going to keep playing around with this, and I added the xml doc contents to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
if(count < txta.text.length)
```

you need to get the length of the text that is in the textarea, not the length of the textarea itself :)

Comment: Ok, i tried this... your suggestion is probably more precise than what I was doing before, but nothing changed. The "if" works fine until it hits the last element in the XMLList, then it ignores my "else" conditions and throws the null error.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY!! I just figured out what my problem was. Carl you were right... I needed to compare my count variable to the storyText.length. My problem was typing it as this:

```
if(count < storyText.length)
```

when i should have typed it as this:

```
if(count < storyText.length())
```

So can anyone tell me why this works? I want to say that adding the () prevents it from being null, but I don't think that's correct. Thanks again for helping me work through this.

Comment: Without reading your main issue… `length` is a property that's widely used e.g. for `String`, `Array` etc. whereas `length()` is an explicit XML property.